# Excel copy/paste values/comments/formats intermittent VBA failure

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have a very large Excel file with 14k+ lines of code and 320+ sheets in it.

The file's VBA imports data from other Excel spreadsheets, does some calculations and "exports" the results.

The "export" involves opening a new workbook and copying across values, formats, comments and the colours of those sheets, then saving that new file.

As part of the code, I have written something that checks the data has been pasted in. Just a very simple:

```
If Range("A2").Value <> True Then
    'error has occured with export
    MsgBox "error", vbCritical, "AURORA Model: Error #MU-ID: Unable to Export Datafile"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

As I say, this error is intermittent and I can't seem to work out what causes it.  I assume it's a memory thing.  Any advice?

Below is the interesting part of the code:

```
Sub ExportData(filename As String, FileLocation As String, export_reason As String)

'
' this macro copys over the values and comments from the model
' this is run by clicking the "butExport" button on the userform
'

Dim sheets_all As Integer
Dim sheets_cycle As Integer
Dim sheet_name As String

Dim sheet_colour As Long

Dim wBook1 As String
Dim wBook2 As String
    'wBook1 is AuRORA
    wBook1 = ThisWorkbook.Name

    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    Workbooks.Add
    'wBook2 is what will be the new datafile
    wBook2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    'activate the Aurora Model
    Windows(wBook1).Activate
    'count the number of sheet in the model
    sheets_all = Sheets.Count

    Sheets("l_ERROR_IPT").ListObjects("tbl_ERROR_IPT").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
    Sheets("l_MRUN").ListObjects("tbl_MRUN").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:=""

    On Error Resume Next
    For sheets_cycle = 1 To sheets_all

        sheet_name = Sheets(sheets_cycle).Name

        Application.StatusBar = _
            "Running Macro. Exporting data " & sheets_cycle _
            & " (" & sheet_name & ") of " & sheets_all & " (" & Round(sheets_cycle / sheets_all * 100, 1) & "%)"

        'if the cycling sheet name begins with s, i, n, l, u, c, o, p or d then...
        If Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "i_" Or Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "u_" _
            Or Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "c_" Or Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "o_" _
            Or Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "p_" Or Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "d_" Or _
            Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "l_" Or Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "s_" Or _
            Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) = "n_" Then
                Sheets(sheets_cycle).Select
                'if it's not a "p_" sheet then show all data
                If Mid(sheet_name, 1, 2) <> "p_" Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
                'copy all cells
                Range("A1:AZ2000").Copy
                sheet_colour = Sheets(sheets_cycle).Tab.Color
                'activate datafile
                Windows(wBook2).Activate
                'paste values and comments
                With Range("A1")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                End With
                'rename sheet with newly pasted data in datafile
                ActiveSheet.Name = sheet_name
                ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = sheet_colour
                'check that cell "A2" = "TRUE" otherwise there has been an error with the export
                If Range("A2").Value <> True Then
                    'error has occured with export
                    MsgBox "error", vbCritical, "AURORA Model: Error #MU-ID: Unable to Export Datafile"
                    Windows(wBook1).Activate
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                'add another sheet
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Windows(wBook1).Activate
        End If
    Next sheets_cycle

    'Delete the last sheet and select the front sheet (d_file_info_sheet)
    Windows(wBook2).Activate
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Delete
    Sheets(1).Select

    'save datafile with a random password
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FileLocation & filename, FileFormat:=50, WriteResPassword:= _
        funcRandNumbersLarge, ReadOnlyRecommended:=True

    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Sheets(1).Select

    MsgBox "Datafile exported and saved as """ & ReconciliationModel.labExportFile.Caption _
        & """. Please check that this has been saved correctly before closing the exported datafile (which has been left open).", vbOKOnly, "AURORA Model: Datafile exported"
```

I'm starting to tear my hair out over this issue so any advice or suggestions would be very welcome!

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Try changing your sheets_cycle loop to a `For Each` style loop instead.

Comment: What's the actual error you are getting? Which line throw it? And what are you trying to achieve with this `If Range("A2").Value <> True Then`?

Comment: Hi,  If I get rid of the line "On Error Resume Next" then the error is thrown up on ".PasteSpecial xlPasteValues".  The message I get is "Run Time Error '1004' PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".  The thing is, if I then move the 'yellow execute line' thing so that it re-copies then attempts pasting again (stepping through it with F8) it works fine.  I continue to run it and then it fails again a few sheets later.  As I said before, it's intermittent - the error isn't always on the same sheet.  the purpose of the "If Range("A2").Value <> True Then" is to catch those failed pastes.

Comment: Hi @SO.  Unfortunately, the `For Each` loop isn't great as I have sheets with up to 50 columns and rows of up to 1500 lines so doing a `For Each cell` on 75,000 cells across 300+ sheets for values, comments and formats isn't the quickest!

Comment: `sheets_cycle` loops through sheets, not the cells?

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, I'll give that a go.  I seemed to only read the `For Each` from your post but ignored the "sheets_cycle".  What I ended up doing was replacing the copy/paste section with a `For Each cell_cycle In transfer_range` and `Workbooks(wBook2).Sheets(paste_sheet_cycle + 1).Range(cell_cycle.Address).Value = cell_cycle.Value` etc.  Anyway, I'll add it now and see if that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are copying large amount of data, you need to clear the memory. after you pasting the values.

Please use the below code at the end of pastespecial line

```
Application.cutcopymode = False
Application.cutcopymode = True
```

Try to use "Activesheet.Range" instead of Range in your code

Comment: Thank you very much, @pasumpon-v-n; `Application.cutcopymode = False` resolved an intermittent "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed" error when pasting rows. It appears that the `Application.cutcopymode = True` line is not necessary in practice (or theory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833319/131415 ).