# Excel stops responding after a while -for loop vba

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, match

When I run the following code excel stops responding after a while(5-6 secs)

What it does:

Gets Value in `e1` checks if present on either of the two sheets `wo` or `wn`
if yes then move the row from which `e1` got it's value to another sheet `wr`
if not found then do nothing

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveEmail()
Dim wi, wn, wo, wr As Worksheet
Dim e1
Dim FinalRowI, FinalRowN, FinalRowO, FinalRow
Dim i, j

Set wi = Sheet2
Set wn = Sheet3
Set wo = Sheet4
Set wr = Sheet5

FinalRowI = wi.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRowN = wn.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRowO = wo.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

FinalRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(FinalRowN, FinalRowO)

For i = 2 To FinalRowI
e1 = Trim(wi.Range("B" & i).Text)
    For j = 2 To FinalRow
        If Trim(wn.Range("C" & j).Text) = e1 Or Trim(wo.Range("C" & j).Text) = e1 Then
         wi.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=wr.Range("A" & wr.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Else: End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are just checking for the *existence* of a value from **wi** in either **wn** or **wo** there are several more efficient methods of looking for it rather than cycling through each row. MATCH or even COUNTIF come immediately to mind.

Comment: @Jeeped but that's not the only purpose I want to move the matched data from `wi` to `wr` as well

Comment: Sure. If it is found then move it across. However, the second (inside) loop could be made much more efficient. Currently, you are not even exiting the loop when found in an inefficient manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be checking the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) unless there is some cell formatting that would change the result. For text (email...?) the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) is the most efficient. Also, once you've located a match and **xlCut** the row out of the original, there is no point in continuing through the loop. Get on with the next value.

```
For i = 2 To FinalRowI
    e1 = Trim(LCase(wi.Range("B" & i).Value2))  'unless you have formatting you want to check, .Text is inefficient
    For j = 2 To FinalRow
        If Trim(lcased(wn.Range("C" & j).Value2)) = e1 Or Trim(LCase(wo.Range("C" & j).Value2)) = e1 Then
            wi.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=wr.Range("A" & wr.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Exit For  'you've cut out the row. no need to continue
        End If
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False  'no need for this on a cut
    Next j
Next i
```

See [Should I turn .CutCopyMode back on before exiting my sub procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833318/should-i-turn-cutcopymode-back-on-before-exiting-my-sub-procedure) for more information on why `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is unnecessary.

Suggest switching to this method using the native worksheet [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

```
For i = 2 To FinalRowI
    e1 = Trim(wi.Range("B" & i).Value2)
    If CBool(Application.CountIf(wn.Columns(3), e1)) Or CBool(Application.CountIf(wr.Columns(1), e1)) Then
        wi.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Cut _
          Destination:=wr.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next i
```

The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is even more efficient but you would have to test for [IsError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx) twice (once for each worksheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :D